# concat underscore templates in a directory to a single js file and load it for use with a backbone app

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, sails.js

I'd like to combine all the underscore templates in a directory to a single js file ( possibly precompile it ? ) for use with the backbonejs part of my sails.js app.

I think I can use the plain fs module with nodejs to read the files and combine them, I'm looking at grunt to do this as well but still not sure.

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grunt to do this. The plugin `grunt-contrib-jst` is what you're looking for; it has installation and usage documents [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst).

A simple Gruntfile.js like this should do it. (This example assumes all your source code is under a `src/` subdirectory, all templates are in *.html files under `src/`, and you're creating an output file in the `build/` subdirectory. Adjust as needed to fit your actual situation.) Run by typing `grunt` on the command line.

Just include the single file `build/view-templates.js` in your index file to load all of your Underscore view templates.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jst');

  grunt.initConfig({
    // compile view templates into single file
    jst: {
        compile: {
            files: {
                "build/view-templates.js": ["src/**/*.html"]
            }
        }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', 'jst' );
};
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! I ended up doing just that. JST plays well with backbone too